# Writing a function that will flatten a two dimensional Array

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, vector, flatten

So, i'm attempting to write a function that flattens a two dimensional vector into a one dimensional vector and returns it. For example:

If I have a matrix of:

8 7 6 3

2 1 9 4

1 2 3 8

It would simply flatten it to a single dimensional vector that contains:

8, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3 , 8,

Though i'm finding a great deal of difficulty with this. Here's what I have so far.

```
std::vector<int> flatten (std::vector< std::vector< int > > vec)
{
    std::vector<int> flattened (begin(vec), end(vec));

    return flattened;

}
```

To my understanding, this is allowing me to create a vector with the values in the first row, but since i'm new to C++, i'm not exactly sure how to go down to the next column and add that row to the flattened vector.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your title really doesn't match the question you are asking.... Think about how you would do it by hand and write code from there.

Answer (score 3):

Write a generic `flatten` method for 2D vectors

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> flatten(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> & vec) {   
    std::vector<T> result;
    for (const auto & v : vec)
        result.insert(result.end(), v.begin(), v.end());                                                                                         
    return result;
}
```

See a working [DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/6lQRWB).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> flatten (std::vector< std::vector< int > > vec)
{
    std::vector<int> flattened;
    for (auto & v : vec){
         std::copy (v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(flattened));
    }
    return flattened;

}
```

Comment: It's saying that class "std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>" has no member append.

Comment: Thank you so much!